# Linux mint17 : error with apt-get

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I 'm new in usinf linux mint. I Try to  install some softwares ,when i use  :

```
apt-get update
```

i get many errors : 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Read about repositories of packages for Ubuntu
   [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu).
2. Keep in mind about those fact that you have links to old version of repository(precise) and because of that these links for packages maybe outdated and not supported anymore.
3. Read already answered similar question
   [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release).